# Is there any way to use a combobox which also acts as suggestbox using GWT 2.7 by allowing two parameters name and it's respective index

Tags: java, gwt, combobox, suggestbox

I want to know how can we use a Combo Box along with auto suggest feature. Please provide example if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [gwt-chosen](https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtchosen) or you create a custom `SuggestBox`